# SpinWait vs Sleep waiting. Which one to use?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it efficient to

```
SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => myPredicate(), 10000)
```

for a timeout of 10000ms

or

Is it more efficient to use `Thread.Sleep` polling for the same condition 
For example something along the lines of the following `SleepWait` function:

```
public bool SleepWait(int timeOut)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); 
    stopwatch.Start();
    while (!myPredicate() && stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < timeOut)
    {
       Thread.Sleep(50)
    }  
    return myPredicate()
}
```

I'm concerned that all the yielding of SpinWait may not be a good usage pattern if we are talking about timeouts over 1sec? Is this a valid assumption?

Which approach do you prefer and why? Is there another even better approach?

---

**Update** - Becoming more specific:

Is there a way to Make BlockingCollection Pulse a sleeping thread when it reaches bounded capacity? I rather avoid a busy waits alltogether as Marc Gravel suggests.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The *best* approach is to have some mechanism to **actively detect** the thing becoming true (rather than passively polling for it having *become* true); this could be any kind of wait-handle, or maybe a `Task` with `Wait`, or maybe an `event` that you can subscribe to to unstick yourself. Of course, if you do that kind of "wait until something happens", that is **still** not as efficient as simply having the next bit of work done *as a callback*, meaning: you don't need to use a thread to wait. `Task` has `ContinueWith` for this, or you can just do the work in an `event` when it gets fired. The `event` is probably the simplest approach, depending on the context. `Task`, however, already provides most-everything you are talking about here, including both "wait with timeout" and "callback" mechanisms.

And yes, spinning for 10 seconds is not great. If you want to use something like your current code, and if you have reason to expect a short delay, but need to allow for a longer one - maybe `SpinWait` for (say) 20ms, and use `Sleep` for the rest?

---

Re the comment; here's how I'd hook an "is it full" mechanism:

```
private readonly object syncLock = new object();
public bool WaitUntilFull(int timeout) {
    if(CollectionIsFull) return true; // I'm assuming we can call this safely
    lock(syncLock) {
        if(CollectionIsFull) return true;
        return Monitor.Wait(syncLock, timeout);
    }
}
```

with, in the "put back into the collection" code:

```
if(CollectionIsFull) {
    lock(syncLock) {
        if(CollectionIsFull) { // double-check with the lock
            Monitor.PulseAll(syncLock);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your answer, this would be nice indeed. Suppose you are tracking use of some resources via a BlockingCollection. They get used (and removed from the collection) and returned to the collection when they are available again for reuse. A shutdown can only happen when all these have returned into the collection. How would you go about signaling that a shutdown can go ahead (ie collection is full again) other than busy waiting?

Comment: @Anastasiosyal I would encapsulate the collection, and have the wrapper do something when full; actually, I'd probably use a `Monitor` for this (will add example)

Comment: In the destructor of an 'ObjectPool' class that descends from BlockingQueue, pop all the objects from the BlockingCollection one-by-one and dispose them, (since this is C#, set the retrieved reference to nil), until the number of objects popped is equal to the pool depth.  All the pooled objects have then been disposed, so you can dispose the queue and return from the dtor to continue the shutdown sequence.  No polling/busywait required!  You may want to put some timeout on the take so that a leaked object eventually raises an exception, (or something).

Comment: @MartinJames - That's a valid comment for most cases. In this instance the owner of the collection isn't being destroyed but returned to a pool (think of a session shutdown and session is returned to a pool)

Comment: Oh - you may want to set a flag so that any thread, (other than the one trying to shut down the pool queue), that tries to take an object from the queue while it is shutting down gets served up an exception instead.

Comment: @Anastasiosyal - OK, then you could pass an 'OnReleased(object thisObject)' delegate as a destructor parameter.  The delegate would get called with objects as they are retrieved and so could return your session objects to wherever they came from.  Alternatively, a suitable delegate gould be passed in as a ctor parameter and stored in a data member until destruction time.

Comment: @MarcGravell Won't this deadlock? Thread 1 Waits until full by Keeping a lock on syncLock and then waiting (Does Monitor have a `WaitOne` method?), Thread 2 attempts to put back into the collection and notify that it is full, but a lock on syncLock is already being held...

Comment: @Anastasiosyal my apologies - it is `Monitor.Wait` - but no: it won't deadlock; that is the normal and well-used technique for using a monitor as a signal. `Wait` releases the lock for the duration, then **re-acquires** the lock before returning either true or false.

Answer (score 137):

In .NET 4 `SpinWait` performs CPU-intensive spinning for 10 iterations before yielding. But it does not return to the caller *immediately* after each of those cycles; instead, it calls `Thread.SpinWait` to spin via the CLR (essentially the OS) for a set time period. This time period is initially a few tens of nano-seconds but doubles with each iteration until the 10 iterations are complete. This enables clarity/predictability in the total time spent spinning (CPU-intensive) phase, which the system can tune according to conditions (number of cores etc.). If `SpinWait` remains in the spin-yielding phase for too long it will periodically sleep to allow other threads to proceed (see [J. Albahari's blog](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_SpinWait) for more information). This process is guaranteed to keep a core busy...

So, `SpinWait` limits the CPU-intensive spinning to a set number of iterations, after which it yields its time slice on every spin (by actually calling `Thread.Yield` and `Thread.Sleep`), lowering its resource consumption. It will also detect if the user is running a single core machine and yield on every cycle if that is the case.

With `Thread.Sleep` the thread is blocked. But this process will not be as expensive as the above in terms of CPU.

Comment: This is copied from Albahari's website. It should be referenced!

Comment: It is not copied verbatim, but was influenced by his site hence why I have referenced his blog.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Its really informative.