# Does Task.Run is able to run lengthy code in background?

Tags: c#, .net-core, task

I have a service solution. (Console executable)

When the request comes from UI, it has to run a couple of operations.

First, based on the request that came from UI, it will fetch records from DB (**The records can be in millions**)

Once the records are available, there is a whole bunch of code that **processes each record and do some publishing**.

The UI will not wait for the whole operation to be completed.

UI should make a call and then the whole lengthy process should run in the background, meanwhile, the service will immediately send a response back to UI

I tried to put the whole long-running code (Fetching of records, processing and publishing) in a separate method.

I am doing like

```
Method()
{
    try
    {
        BackgroundProcessing();
        return true;
    }
    Catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // logging of exception
        return false;
    }

}

async void BackgroundProcessing()
{
    await Task.Run( () =>
    {
            // Fetching of records
           // Processing of records
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes potentially, `await Task.Run(Method)`, which will potentially start a new thread, and give you a continuation back on the UI thread. There are only few use cases for `Task.Factory.StartNew` in modern .net, where you know better and would like to use explicit options not available in `Task.Run`, and additionally are aware of the problems it can cause.

Comment: If this operation works purely with database data, then you'll probably find that it's much quicker to execute it in the database.

Comment: @ Michael Randall: 

I have edited the question.

 Are you suggesting that way?
 
My only concern is whether this will support the long-running process.

@Nick: Anyway, I need to get those data from Db to service for individual processing.

Comment: Yes it will, however it will tie up a thread-pool thread using `Task.Run`. You could use the `LongRunning` hint to suggest that it should use a background thread with `Task.Factory.StartNew` take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921191/how-to-pass-longrunning-flag-specifically-to-task-run

Comment: @Michael Randall:  So that means without specifying LongRunning, it will not be able to handle such a large running background process?

Comment: `Task.Run` will run fine and has certain benefits, and will achieve everything you want to acheive. If you have a problem (which id doubt), you can look at `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: _"what's best"_ questions are primarily opinion based and unsuitable for Stack Overflow. _"any better way"_ questions are too broad. If you want to understand whether `Task.Run()` is more suitable for your scenario than `StartNew()`, see duplicate. Please read [ask] and other on-site resources so that you understand better what makes a suitable, well-written question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: In the vast majority of situations, the thread pool will adjust to any long-running task in 0.5 seconds - without the LongRunning flag. Most likely, you don’t really need it.

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html