# Is there a way to run an async method as a LongRunning task?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm looking to run an async method as a long-running thread, as in using the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` option. In my testing I'm considering the thread as running as a "long-running" thread if it is *not* a thread-pool thread (i.e. I expect that `Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread` will be false).

This is my attempt:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWorkAsync,
            CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
task.Unwrap().Wait();

static async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("IsThreadPoolThread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("IsThreadPoolThread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
}
```

The output of this is:

```
IsThreadPoolThread: False
IsThreadPoolThread: True
```

meaning that after the first `await` the thread is no longer like a long-running thread.

This outcome intuitively makes sense as I'm passing the `TaskFactory.StartNew()` method a `Func<Task>` where the generic type of `Task` is simply interpreted as the result type of the `Task` that is created by `TaskFactory.StartNew()`, so I end up getting a `Task<Task>` which completes once the async method returns its `Task`, i.e. once the first `await` statement is encountered.

Is there a way to have the entire execution of the async method run as a long-running thread, i.e. to have all continuations run as non-thread-pool threads?

Comment: `the thread is no longer`  the thread itself is different. After `await` execution resumes on a threadpool thread. Tasks aren't threads nor do they correspond to a specific thread. What are you trying to do? Why did you use `LongRunning` in the first place?

Comment: `async` itself doesn't make a method run in the background. It tells the compiler to generate the infrastructure that allows using `await` to await other tasks. Everything up to the first `await` still runs on the calling thread

Comment: `LongRunning` only makes sense for heavily CPU bound (blocking) tasks, which do not `await`. It makes no sense to use on a proper `async` function, as soon as you hit the first `await` the task will be parked anyway. If the task is long running *in between* `await`s then maybe you could use a custom scheduler.

Comment: Why exactly do you want that? P.S. `Task.Delay(100).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` =)))))

Comment: Typically tasks are running on [no threads](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html "There is no thread"). It is possible to run the `await` continuations on a dedicated thread, by using a custom `TaskScheduler` like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379898/moving-database-calls-to-a-separate-thread-without-busy-wait/58397942#58397942), but do you really have any specific reason to do that?

Comment: It's possible to do this: create a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext` on a dedicated thread (e.g., `AsyncContext` from my AsyncEx library). The question is: why do you feel a need to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass LongRunning flag specifically to Task.Run()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921191/how-to-pass-longrunning-flag-specifically-to-task-run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the helpful comments on this question!

As @Theodor Zoulias pointed out, this is possible to do by using a custom `TaskScheduler`.

However, the best answer to "how do you run an async method as a LongRunning task?" is probably "You don't". As @Charlieface pointed out the `LongRunning` task option only makes sense for long-running blocking threads. The use of coroutines (achieved via the async/await construct) defeats the `LongRunning` option because whenever an `await` is encountered the relevant thread will be released and returned to the thread pool.

Comment: What question does this answer? What's the actual question? The phrase `how do you run an async method as a LongRunning task?" is probably` has no meaning. `LongRunning` isn't a task type, it's an instruction to the task scheduler that work may take a long time. It's up to the scheduler to decide whether a new thread will be created, or another will be reused

Comment: This is semantics, but the question could have been phrased as "how do I tell the task scheduler to run the task representing the async method as a long-running task?". It seemed like there was no way to do this since in the code example the `LongRunning` option applies to the implicit `Func<Task>` which only represents the work of running the async method up until the first await statement.

However, the fact which anyone asking this question probably doesn't realize is that the use of coroutines defeats the `LongRunning` option so that the question becomes non-applicable.

Comment: It's not semantics, which is why you seem to still be confused about tasks. The insistence of talking about coroutines suggest you're trying to apply a mental model from a different language to .NET. Even talking about `long running async method` is self-contradictory: async operations don't use threads and the `async` keyword doesn't make a method run in the background. When `await` is used the executing thread is released. So why do you want to use the `LongRunning` hint if your method yields while awaiting anyway?

Comment: Is your *real* question how to go back to the original thread? Well, that's the default behavior in GUI applications, but not due to any task options. It's `await` that resumes execution after a task is complete. `await` will resume execution in the original synchronization context. In GUI applications, that's the UI thread. In web applications, it's another threadpool thread with the entire request context restored. In console applications there's no synchronization context. If that's what you ask, why do you want to go back to the original thread?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos To my knowledge `async/await` in C# is a syntactic mechanism for leveraging coroutines. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine#C.23. In my previous comment I said "the fact which anyone asking this question probably doesn't realize is that the use of coroutines defeats the LongRunning option so that the question becomes non-applicable". Your comment expressed that same notion just using different words. As I explained my question had already been answered so there's no point in continuing the discussion as it's just going in circles at this point.