# WCF Web Service Crashes on While Loop

Tags: c#, wcf, while-loop, crash, client

I'm creating a WCF Client that contains a while loop with a timer to obtain pricedata and send pricedata from a web service every x seconds, as long as the stop button is not pressed. The relevant code looks like this:

```
// Starts the while loop
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stopped = false; 
    // The Indicator is green when on and red when off.
    Indicator.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkSeaGreen;
    Table.DataSource = client.GetPrices().ToList();

    while (!Stopped)
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText(directory + filename);
        client.SendPrices(content);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); 
        Table.DataSource = client.GetPrices().ToList();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    } 
}

// Stops the while loop
private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Indicator.BackColor = Color.Red;
    Stopped = true; 
}
```

The problem is that the code compiles normally and shows no warnings, but somehow the while loop crashes after I press the start button. What is going wrong with this code?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting when it crashes?

Comment: There is no error, it just hangs and responds no more. However, if i leave out the while loop, but not the inner code, everything works fine

Comment: You have got a "busy wait" on the UI thread, which is bad news. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719003/spinwait-vs-sleep-waiting-which-one-to-use etc.

Comment: How can I do that in this specific case? I have no clue.

Comment: When you press the start button, your while loop blocks the UI, so you won't be able to push the stop button.  You should run it on a background thread or asynchronously.   Look into BackgroundWorker or async/await - lots of examples on the web.