# Limit CPU usage in conjunction with Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#

### What i need :

I need to run an array of methods in multithreading with maximum 1 thread per core.   Each of these thread need to have a throttling feature to be able to limit CPU usage of all threads. If i specify 10% on 4 core running 3 threads (because i choose 3 was the max) all 3 threads need to not take more than 10% CPU usage per core. Something exactly how some application like Steam where you can limit the download speed but imagine you would have multiple internet connection to represent the multi core.

### What i tried :

I have tried using `Task` but i couldn't figure out how to manage the maximum amount of threads it create and even less which core they each uses.

### What i end up having :

I ended up finding `Parallel.ForEach` with combinaison of `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` gives me exactly the control that i want over the amount of threads. I know how much cores i have and i can easily make something to let the user pick the amount of core to use. My test concluded that `Parallel.ForEach` attribute work on each core in a sequence and once all core have received something it loop back and reassign again. Which is perfect. If i set parallelism of 3 on a 4 core i get 3 thread on 3 different core, while setting parallelism of 5 on a 4 core then 3 core will have 1 thread and 1 core will have 2. That behavior is exactly what i need. This method is not set in stone i am open to changes.

### CPU limitation

Now using the `Parallel.ForEach` make the cpu work 100% of the time which is a big problem in that tight environment where any usage over 40-50% over a long period of time over many computers increase the wattage drawn so much that it trigger a critical alarm in the building and we need to be below that. Anyhow i have not found any solution other than doing a thread.sleep in the tight loop but that still make the cpu run 100% for couple seconds then nearly 0% for longer period and then it does that over and over again. This did not work. I ran a small test in one of the room with barely 150 computers and half of them spiked at 100% at the nearly the same exact time drawing WAY too much power. My second test was to use only the 8 cores or more and run on 1 core only and that manage to reduce the usage by a lot.

### Priority

I have finally tested with Process priority and it's not better. Yes the process receive way less CPU time but the cpu still run at 100% when i does get power. Unless i have miss a critical option when dealing with the priority that can limit the CPU.

### Finally

I have the feeling i am very close with `Parallel.ForEach` i am just missing the CPU limitation per core. Am i missing just 1 thing ? I know that using `Thread.Sleep` is completely stupid as it actually limit the time the cpu is used and not the amount.

### For those who want code

again this is prototype so the code is pretty much useless. All it does it run code on many cpu until it finishes

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue - 100);

    Parallel.ForEach(
             items,
             new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
             value => { Calculate(value); }
     );
}

private static void Calculate(int value)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait(100000);
    var test = value;
    test *= -1;
    Console.WriteLine(test);
}
```

Comment: thats what `SpinWait` does.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9719357/23528

Comment: @DanielA.White So you mean that technically `SpinWait` should be giving me a way to reduce my CPU usage ? The code i posted i started with 1000 and added zeroes until i can see a difference and it doesn't change anything. CPU still hit 60-70% per core.

Comment: no im saying spin wait puts that load.

Comment: @DanielA.White Ah ok i get what you mean. Anyway `SpinWait` i originally put it there to replace `Thread.Sleep` to see how it affected the CPU usage. Not good either.

Comment: Where is the point in firing up 4 CPUs at 50% when you could just run 2 CPUs at 100%? In other words: Why not limit your threads to *half* the CPUs?

Comment: @nvoigt Some computers are 2 and 4 cores. in the case of lets use 2 cores. running 100% on 1 core has a too big watts being consumed. Like i mentioned in my test on 8 core chips running 100% on 1 core is nearly like running 10% on all 8 cores (watt wise) so it would work. But i need to use that on all computers. Majority are 4 cores, couple of 2 cores, few 6 cores and quite rare 8 cores. That method would work on maybe 20-30 computers out of the 900-ish which is not acceptable

Comment: what kind of work are you actually doing? that might help us maybe find a better way.

Comment: @DanielA.White Well i don't know if you would understand all of this but it's a highly custom machine learning, FEA predictions, DNA samplings, Thermodynamics balancing mesh of computers and servers. Plus super sampler IO on the network for chemicals analysis. These machine need to be cost efficient and the equipment around them at extremely sensitive to temperature changes so wattage is a big concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windows Job Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/job-objects) to limit the CPU usage of an entire process (or process tree). You can limit your whole process or start a child worker process that you limit.

This requires PInvoke (which is not too hard here) and does not allow you to control specific threads (which seems not needed here).

Alternatively, you need to do your own throttling (since you stated that merely controlling the number of threads does not work for you). I would base it in [`PauseToken`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2013/01/13/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods/). Any easy way to throttle to 75% would be this:

```
var pauseToken = new PauseToken();

//Use pauseToken on all threads that consume a lot of CPU

Task.Run(async () => {
 while (true) {
  await Task.Delay(250); //run
  pauseToken.Pause();
  await Task.Delay(750); //pause
  pauseToken.Resume();
 }
});
```

You could even adapt the percentage of throttling dynamically. Read the power usage of the device each second. If it is above a certain threshold, increase pause percentage by 10%. If it is below, decrease pause percentage by 5%. That way you can very easily target a specific wattage.

Comment: That sound very good. I do have the actual power usage of the computer through a usb probe that update at rate of 8 samples each 1/6000th of a second. Maybe 1 small question. Is there a way to force the core where a `Task` run or the easiest is really making a thread and setting CPU affinity there ?

Comment: Tasks do not have CPU affinity. You need to do this through threads. With the `LongRunning` option you have one thread per task. You can then set CPU affinity inside that task's code on the first line. That gives you the convenience of tasks with thread control. Or, use a TaskScheduler but that would work slightly differently.

Comment: Your usage for the PauseToken is not matching the link at all. I'll have to take more time and look at Windows Job Object.

Comment: @Franck yeah, I just wrote pseudo-code. It's the same concept and the article is well written. If you have trouble understanding it feel free to ask.

Comment: their own sample is not working as they describe on my end. The pause doesn't actually pause the current process which is bad in my case. Putting it in a separate thread is worst and doesn't pause the main thread either. I am going to look more into the Window Job Object. I have other people looking into testing other softwares that already exist that can limit cpu usage by percentage on any application you want. I find it very strange that it seems super easy with third party option and is so complicated to do with C#

Comment: Pausing threads is cooperative. Your worker threads must poll the pause token. The poll will pause until the token is unpaused. You can also uncooperatively pause threads with Thread.Suspend/Resume but that is very unsafe. You'd need an external process that suspends the entire .NET process.