# Async wait for boolean value

Tags: c#, asynchronous, wait

Hi I simply want to wait for a boolean var to be True in an async fashion (non blocking the main thread) e.g.

> bool _Loaded = false SomeData TheData;
>
> public async Task<> DoSomething()     {
>           await _Loaded == true;
>           DoSomethingNowItsLoaded();     }

Or wait for a function to be called.

Comment: Please tag with programming language (and framework if applicable).

Comment: The question is not clear. Could you define the problem in more general form?

Answer (score 2):

The following will work:

```
public async Task DoSomething() {
    System.Threading.SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => _Loaded);
    DoSomethingNowItsLoaded(); 
}
```

Although, I recommend [Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/) instead of waiting until a boolean becomes true. [This is a great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719003/spinwait-vs-sleep-waiting-which-one-to-use) of why that is.

That would look something like this:

```
event EventHandler<EventArgs> LoadedEvent;

Constructor() {
    LoadedEvent += LoadEventHandler;
}

public void Load() {
    .... Do some work to load some things ....
    LoadedEvent?.Invoke(this, null);
}

private void LoadEventHandler(EventArgs e) {
    DoSomethingNowThatItsLoaded();
}
```